# Gem therubyracer does not install even if libv8 is installed

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have installed `libv8` gem on windows by using this command:

```
gem install libv8 -- --with-system-v8
```

Then when I try to install `therubyracer` it gives me long error message:

```
Installing therubyracer 0.12.2 with native extensions

Gem::Ext::BuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

current directory: D:/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/therubyracer- 0.12.2/ext/v8
D:/Ruby21-x64/bin/ruby.exe -r ./siteconf20160105-4924-101vdyd.rb extconf.rb
checking for main() in -lpthread... yes
checking for v8.h... no
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may
need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:

--with-opt-dir
--without-opt-dir
--with-opt-include
--without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
--with-opt-lib
--without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
--with-make-prog
--without-make-prog
--srcdir=.
--curdir
--ruby=D:/Ruby21-x64/bin/ruby
--with-pthreadlib
--without-pthreadlib
--enable-debug
--disable-debug
--with-v8-dir
--without-v8-dir
--with-v8-include
--without-v8-include=${v8-dir}/include
--with-v8-lib
--without-v8-lib=${v8-dir}/lib
D:/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/libv8-3.16.14.13/ext/libv8/location.rb:50:in `configure': You have chosen to use the version of V8 found on your system (Libv8::Location::System::NotFoundError)
and *not* the one that is bundle with the libv8 rubygem. However,
it could not be located. please make sure you have a version of
v8 that is compatible with 3.16.14.13 installed. You may
need to special --with-v8-dir options if it is in a non-standard
location

thanks,
The Mgmt
```

What I understood is that therubyracer wants to find `v8`. I have installed Node.js which already has it. Is it even possible to use it? Or there are other solutions for therubyracer?

Comment: Cannot help that much, because I just use Linux, but you need the "devel" (source) files for v8. `checking for v8.h... no`

Comment: As Paulo said, you need devel version for v8 .May be you could try installing `nodejs` on your box instead of working around that with `therubyracer`, if you are trying to run your `rake` tasks only.

Comment: I have downloaded raw source of v8 from github, how to install therubyracer with it?

Answer (score 78, accepted):

This bug appears in OS X El Capitan.
Just use `v8@3.15` for `therubyracer`.

```
brew install v8@3.15
bundle config --local build.libv8 --with-system-v8
bundle config --local build.therubyracer --with-v8-dir=/usr/local/opt/v8@3.15
bundle install
```

[Check detail of this issue](https://github.com/cowboyd/therubyracer/issues/398)

Comment: Thanks this worked great for me. I was getting that message as well: "Make sure that `gem install therubyracer -v '0.12.2'` succeeds before bundling."

Comment: I concur, using therubyracer 0.12.2 and setting these bundle config options worked for me.  I used this option mostly because it fixes the issue in a way I can actually use with a Gemfile AND deals doesn't cause any weird problems on deployment

Comment: `Error: No available formula with the name "v8-315"`

Comment: I was wondering if someone has a solution for the Mac M1 chip, this solution works for the intel chic I believe. Am using the MacBook pro M1 MacOS Monterey

Comment: Anything for Ubuntu?

Answer (score 4):

I was also facing this issue and spent a lot of time on it. Here what works for me.

```
$ brew install v8@3.15
$ bundle config build.libv8 --with-system-v8
$ bundle config build.therubyracer --with-v8-dir=$(brew --prefix v8@3.15)
$ bundle install
```

Comment: That worked. Now I've got to deal with pg, but we're getting there. Thank you! (OSX Monterey v 12.3.1)

Answer (score 4):

On MacOS Mojave this works ok:

1. install v8@3.15

   ```
   brew install v8@3.15
   ```
2. edit profile(in my case `vi ~/.zshrc`) and add this:

   ```
   export PATH="/usr/local/opt/v8@3.15/bin:$PATH"
   export LDFLAGS="-L/usr/local/opt/v8@3.15/lib"
   export CPPFLAGS="-I/usr/local/opt/v8@3.15/include"
   ```
3. install therubyracer version in this case 0.12.2:

   ```
   gem install therubyracer -v '0.12.2' -- --with-v8-dir=/usr/local/opt/v8@3.15
   ```

Answer (score 2):

@sushilprj's advice worked like a charm.

I just needed to run one extra thing because I got the following message after trying "brew install v8@3.15"

> Error: The following directories are not writable by your user:
> /usr/local/share/man/man5
>
> You should change the ownership of these directories to your user.
> sudo chown -R $(whoami) /usr/local/share/man/man5

So, I executed:

```
$sudo chown -R $(whoami) /usr/local/share/man/man5
```

and then I executed the 4 commands that @sushilprj suggested.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you need therubyracer - it turned out that for our case we don't need it at all and just removed it and used node - https://kmitov.com/posts/we-dont-need-therubyracer-and-the-libv8-error-for-compiling-native-extensions/